# What font does Benchmark email use?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Benchmarkemail uses a nice font for the logo. I've already tried with several image to font services but no one is accurate. The url is: http://www.benchmarkemail.com/

[image]

Comment: you can use this bookmarklet to view mobile fonts...you'll need to tinker though: https://github.com/chengyin/WhatFont-Bookmarklet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font in question is [Wisdom script](http://jamestedmondson.com/typefaces/Wisdom_Script) by James Edmondson.

[image]

letters:

[image]